# Python/QT Live Application Log in QML

Tags: python, logging, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to create a live log of all console output in the QML GUI.
I want to emit a QT signal every time Python writes to stdout/stderr.  I am using Python 3.8. Here is my code that performs logging of QML output and Python interpreter stderr by writing to a file and the console.

```
class Log(QObject, object):

    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.DEBUG,
            format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
            handlers=[
                logging.FileHandler("debug.log", mode='w'),
                logging.StreamHandler()
            ]
        )
        qInstallMessageHandler(self.qt_message_handler)

    def qt_message_handler(self, mode, context, message):
        log_entry = "%s: %s (%s:%d, %s)" % (mode.name.decode(), message, context.file, context.line, context.file)
        logging.warning(log_entry)
```

Comment: updated my post

Comment: If you are trying to create an IDE-like application, you should probably start another Python instance in a subprocess. Then you can catch its stdout/stderr easily; also "sandbox" and "gui" environments should be clearly separated. You can use ``sys.prefix`` to get the executable of the current interpreter.

Comment: @Torben Klein Okay, interesting. I know how to create another Python instance but what would the command be? python3 sys.prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to catch:

Regular log messages? Use an own logging handler:

```
class MyLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        """Do whatever you need with the record"""
# somewhere appropriate
logging.getLogger().addHandler(MyLogHandler())
```

Output of print statement? You can catch and convert into log messages. I use somethin like this in my programs to catch leftover print() calls:

```
real_print = print
def _print(*stuff, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush):
    if not (file is sys.stdout or file is None):
        return real_print(*stuff, sep=sep, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
    text = sep.join(str(thing) for thing in stuff)
    # replace by other logging call as desired
    # e.g. add file / lineno information
    logging.info(text)
__builtins__['print'] = _print
```

Unregulated output to stdout / stderr (C libraries): This is a bit more complicated. If possible, you can isolate the part of the code that outputs things into a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). You can then take its output from the Subprocess object properties.

Otherwise, you can fiddle around with sys.stdout / sys.stderr, but I suspect this won't help with C libs (never tried myself).

In any case, **be extra careful with error handling** when doing log stuff. Vanishing log messages are a ticket for hours of debugging fun.

EDIT: If you are trying to create an IDE-like application, you should probably start another Python instance in a subprocess. Then you can catch its stdout/stderr easily; also "sandbox" and "gui" environments should be clearly separated.

Proof-of-concept:

```
import sys
import subprocess
# runs python --version
sp = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "--version"])
print(sp.stdout)
```

For "real" work you would of course omit the `--version` arg, and send input to sp.stdin somehow.

Comment: I am getting this error when i use your first approach. AttributeError: 'MyLogHandler' object has no attribute 'formatter'. I copied your first approach and added MyLogHandler() to my handlers=[ ] list.

Comment: Strange, works fine here... Dumb question, did you inherit from ``logging.Handler``?

Comment: yes I did, its not showing an error anymore, but the emit method is not being executed.. weird

Comment: your proof of concept seems like it would work, just seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Don't think so, in fact you should do this to execute "untrusted" code. Besides logging, there is lots of "damage" that user code can do, e.g. zombie threads, changing global variables or functions, blocking I/O... so you will want to have it in an environment where you can just kill it off and restart.